# Maven and Nexus strategy for multi javaee versions

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, nexus

I have an application that needs to be updated for various versions of javaee. I have the 1.1 version will be generated with support for JavaEE5 and version 1.2 will be generated for JavaEE6, just that maybe I need to generate version 1.3 to version JavaEE5 and JavaEE6 version. With that always need to keep changing my pom to match om one platform or another. I need to change maven configuration on each release:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>                 
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion><!--Change for 3.1 if use javaee6-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version><!--Plataform version-->
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules></modules>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                <applicationName>${project.artifactId}</applicationName>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What kind of branch strategy can I use?

Comment: Should there be a branch strategy involved? A project management strategy might be more appropriate. Have two deployable pom-only projects (or modules might be better), each dependent on the main project, and each configured in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow why you need to change the version. You can deploy EJB 3.0 modules to Java EE 5 or 6 servers. The code itself isn't changing so you might as well package using the minimal version that you support.

That said, you could use Maven profiles to pass different parameters to the pom for the scenarios.